# Enforcing type hints in a Python CI/CD

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylint, python-typing, python-3.9

**My Problem**

I am a part of a team that's building a big microservice project with Python. For obvious reasons, we'd like to specifically declare the types of arguments and return values for the functions and methods that we share. However, I could not find a way to enforce [Python type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) as a part of our [github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) CI/CD pipeline.

**What Have I Tried**

We're using [black](https://github.com/psf/black) and [Pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint), so I tried to find a proper PyLint configuration, but did not find any.

**My Question**

Is there a way to enforce Python type hints in a CI/CD process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [MyPy](https://github.com/python/mypy), not PyLint. It's well-maintained and has good configuration options (like [ignoring specific parts of the code](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20form,purpose%20of%20the%20comment%20is.)).